# Python PyCaret script in Microsoft Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi, pycaret

I try to run this script in Power BI:

```
from pycaret.anomaly import *
dataset = get_outliers(dataset, ignore_features=['DEPT_NAME', 'MERCHANT', 'TRANS_DT'])
```

I got the script from https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/learn-pycaret/official-blog/anomaly-detector-in-power-bi-using-pycaret

But I get this error:

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Ρуŧнόл śςѓïрŧ êŗгôř.
<pi>NameError: name 'get_outliers' is not defined
</pi>
Detaljer:
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=Ρуŧнόл śςѓïрŧ êŗгôř.
<pi>NameError: name 'get_outliers' is not defined
</pi>
    ErrorCode=-2147467259
```

As I read it there is a problem with: get_outliers

I have no clue of what to do, I have searchede but I cant get any answer there solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you using PyCaret 3.x but in the tutorial is PyCaret 2.x. They remove `get_outliers()` in 3.x but the underlying of this function is the wrapper of the following steps

1. setup()
2. create_model()
3. assign_model()

You need to write this way to get the same results as the tutorial

```py
from pycaret.anomaly import *
setup(dataset, ignore_features=['DEPT_NAME', 'MERCHANT', 'TRANS_DT'], verbose=False)
c = create_model(model='knn', fraction=0.05)
dataset = assign_model(c, verbose=False)
```

[image: power_bi_results]

You can find implementation of `get_outliers()` in PyCaret 2.x from [here](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/1eff59610b86f3719688570c4b4f0cf6a4de933c/pycaret/anomaly.py#L1277) and tutorial about anomaly detection in PyCaret 3.x from [here](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial%20-%20Anomaly%20Detection.ipynb)